# linux server misbehaving

Tags: linux, memory

i ran the script below

```
ps --no-headers -eo user,rss | awk '{arr[$1]+=$2}; END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]/1024/1024}}' | sort -nk2 -r
```

it shows that the memory usage is approx 12GB however the top command shows total memory is 66 GB used is 63 GB free is 3 GB

Numbers above are approximate.
Here is an update showing similar numbers using command `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64521      64087        433          0       2071      51567

-/+ buffers/cache:      10449      54072
Swap:        63999          1      63998
```

Why is 63 GB used when the above command shows used is 12 GB?

my server misbehaves and the processes start hanging when free memory according to top command is low

This is a HP server with 66GB RAM, running Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.3 64 bit (basically Red Hat)

Any clues ?

Comment: free -m
                 total          used        free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64521      64136        385          0       2037      51622
-/+ buffers/cache:      10476      54045
Swap:        63999          1      63998

Comment: oracle enterprise linux 6.3 64 bit which is basically Red hat

Answer (score 4):

Your server is not misbehaving. You are mistaken on how to interpret the output of `free`. See https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free: "buffers" and "cached" designate memory "in use", but the cache can be dropped immediately. That is why "buffers" and "cached" counts towards the amount of memory actually available to be used by applications.

http://thoughtsbyclayg.blogspot.com/2008/09/display-free-memory-on-linux-ubuntu.html says

> When thinking about 'how much memory is really free', I want to calculate:
> 'free' + ('buffers' + 'cached')

In your example, there are 54 GB memory ready to be used by applications.

Comment: so - memory is not an issue - Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Rajan if this answer helped you please remember to accept it with the tick mark